# Collection URL is not working when Collection Name for VSTS is appended to the Account URL

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have my VSTS at https://xyz.visualstudio.com. This is my account URL.

When I browse all projects I see that the collection name is shown as xyz.

But when I use it to form the collection URL (like in on-premises TFS Collection URL https://tfsURL.domain.com/CollectionName), https://xyz.visualstudio.com/xyz I get 404 page.

Rather if I use DefaultCollection in place for xyz I don't get any error but land my in my VSTS home page.

Is this the case for everyone?

If that is the case the Collection Name should appear as "Default Collection" in the VSTS.

[image: Collection Name shown in VSTS]

I stumbled upon this scenario as I was setting up an on-premises build agent for VSTS, which requires me to put the Collection URL.

Updated:

Error I get when I use https://xyz.visualstudio.com for the Service URL while connecting to VSTS from TFX-CLI.

[image: ErrorWhileNotusingCollectionNameforServiceURL]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The collection name is defaultcollection and it is working for me. (https://starain.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection)

》》I stumbled upon this scenario as I was setting up an on-premises build agent for VSTS, which requires me to put the Collection URL.

You just need to type https://xyz.visualstudio.com if you configure build agent.

You need to specify https://xyz.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection if you are using tfx command

Comment: When I use https://xyz.visualstudio.com for the Service URL, I get the error as "Provided URL https://xyz.visualstudio.com" is not a collection-level URL. Ensure the URL contains a collection, e.g. https://fabrikam.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection."

I have copied the screenshot in my blog, and updated the screenshot in the question for easy reference.

[link](https://baskisumiwordpresscom.wordpress.com/2016/11/24/collection-url-for-tfx-cli/)

Comment: @BaskarLingamRamachandran Based on your blog, https://XXX.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection works fine, am I right? (defaultcollection works fine for me too)

Comment: Yes with the collection name as DefaultCollection it works. However the collection name in VSTS is not DefaultCollection. The collection name is XXX. Let me inform this to VSTS team ! Thank you.

Comment: There is just a collection and its name is DefaultCollection.

Comment: Okay. Ideally in that case, the collection name should appear as DefaultCollection when I click on Browse in my home page, as shown in the screenshot in the question.

VSTS team needs to change the display name of the collection in VSTS page to be DefaultCollection, rather than something like xyz.

Comment: I'm using the VSTS Team services Continuous Deployment plugin from Jenkins. And I was having some issues when using the Collection url which lead me to here. And I use 'https://username.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection' as sugested by @starianchen-MSFT and tthat fix my 404 not found error. Hopeffuly this information would help somebody else using the same set up as me for CI/CD.